# How to discontinue dd if the output file is /dev/sda?

Tags: sudo, dd

It's not necessary to explain the surprise on running

```
sudo dd if=/path of=/dev/sda
```

sda or whatever the name of your HDD is.

Is there a way in which I can stop that from happening?

Answers can also include ways (scripts or tools) to stop dangerous commands such as above from hampering HDD or devices of choice.

Comment: It is hard to understand your question, if you think a command is dangerous, don't run it.

Comment: @MarkKirby you did'nt mean the command itself... i meant the dangerous instance of theirs... (had you read it carefully)

Comment: I don't understand that comment either! "you did'nt mean the command itself" `?` "i meant the dangerous instance of theirs" There what? FYI four others agree with me, I have no issues with my reading.

Comment: Of course, no matter how carefully you guard against `dd of=/dev/sda`, you're still vulnerable to `cat > /dev/sda`, and `cp /dev/zero /dev/sda`, and `sort -o /dev/sda`, and...

Comment: @SteveSummit "dangerous commands such as above" isn't that's what i am asking a solution for?

Comment: @juggernaut1996 Everyone was focusing on `dd`, so I was pointing out that there are other dangers, but you knew that,.

Comment: My basic answer is the same as the others: traditionally, the way to avoid accidentally writing to a critical file like `/dev/sda` is to protect it so only root can write to it.  So you've got to be very careful when running things as root!  Otherwise there are lots of things you can all too easily break.  Me, I do as little as possible as root.  Every time I do something as root, I'm thinking about the fact that there's no other way to do it, and it's appropriate for only root to be able to do it, and that I've got to double-check before hitting RETURN.

Comment: Some people (not saying you) are in the habit of logging in as root and doing everything as root, or of putting `sudo` in front of everything.  Me, I think that's both foolish and dangerous, like taking the safety guards off your circular saw and leaving them off.

Comment: One thing you can do is to change the `sudoers` config file to restrict the commands that `sudo` will let you run.  If there's a command that's too dangerous, or that you've discovered is too easy to accidentally misuse, you can disallow it.  (But of course that disallows *all* sudo uses of the command, not just the ones that, say, write to `/dev/sda`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following into `/usr/bin/dd`:

```bsh
if [[ "$*" != *"of=/dev/sda"* ]]; then
    /bin/dd "$*"
else
    echo "You are not allowed to set dd output to /dev/sda!"
fi
```

NOTE: If, in case, you ever need to *actually* use `dd` on `/dev/sda`, use

```
sudo /bin/dd [Arguments for dd]
```

**To downvoters: The issue pointed out by @Gilles (Thanks!) has been fixed now, no need to downvote.**

Comment: I like this, however, an improvement might be to simply take the args and repeat them back to them.  Source= ? (yes/no) / Destination = ? (yes/no)

Comment: @bc2946088 Then `dd` would not work unattended/in scripts, so…

Comment: that did it... however i tried it in VM ;)

Comment: I would never do this. Define the function, but *with a different name*. One day you'll be on a machine that doesn't have it defined and depend on it being defined, and then you'll regret it.

Comment: @ReinierPost 1) This is just a safeguard for personal machines 2) No attacker/malicious script will explicitly use our custom `dd`, which which is what OP wants to protect themselves from.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Raju: Yes, I know.

Comment: @juggernaut1996 This answer is completely wrong. `sudo dd` always invokes the command, never the function. Defining a `dd` function only overrides what happens if you run `dd` *without* `sudo`. (`sudo` doesn't read any bash configuration, bash does. `sudo bash` reads `.bashrc`, `sudo dd` doesn't.)

Comment: @Gilles So is there a way to fix that? Does `/etc/bash.bashrc` work?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju no, it won't. You need to use a script and not a function. For example, create `/usr/bin/dd` (you need a script called `dd` that is in i) a directory in your $PATH and ii) in a directory that is before `/bin` (where `dd` is)) and have that  script do what your function does.

Comment: @Gilles Fixed answer. `/usr/bin` is before `/bin` in `$PATH`.

Comment: @juggernaut1996 It works now.

Comment: "Can I have my votes back now?" The downvoters are not the same people as the upvoters, you have +4/-4 this means you gained 40 but lost 8 rep, I tell you this to soften the blow of the fact most of these voters likely won't revisit the question to revise there vote, sorry, but at least you still made 32 rep :)

Comment: @MarkKirby So downvotes don't give -10? I thought they did...

Comment: Nope, just -2, if you look in your profile at your answers, you should see +32 for this one.

Answer (score 7):

Running commands with sudo is inherently dangerous because of the rights that come with it; therefore use it judiciously and with care.  The best way to stop bad things happening is to think twice and act once.

Comment: yeah that woudl always work... i was expecting something for misclicks amd hasty situations

Answer (score 1):

You might want to learn to use ddrescue.

Enable the univers-repository (if you haven't allready) and install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gddrescue
```

Using ddrescue is much less error prone and thus less dangerous. Also it features neat things like a *progress bar*.